# Where does the [sic] go in this sentence?

Tags: quotes, typography

I'm [quoting a sentence](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3725/41775) that has an error in it.

> ...visitors need to need to apply for a temporary residence permit...

I don't want to correct the error, I want to quote it as it's written. But I want to put a [sic] in there. Where does the [sic] go? Also, should it be in (parentheses) or [brackets]?

Comment: Why would you want to maintain that? If you remove it you won't have to worry about the position of '[sic]' also.

Comment: @Mitch Here's the reasoning behind it: http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/a/3726/41775

Comment: OK. that is wrong in spirit and in letter. The '[sic]' goes either at the end of the error or better, at the end of the passage _or_ you certainly can just fix a terrible typo like that. It's more professional to show that, unless you are a literary scholar quoting a passage for the study of typos.

Comment: @Mitch That comment sounds like an answer, no?

Comment: Fiksdal, yes but would take me time to check an authoritative reference

Comment: @Mitch Alright.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Place *[sic]* after the second repetition error.

It would read:

> ... visitors need to need to [sic] apply for a temporary...

Editorial (your) additions are placed in square brackets.

Comment: Strictly, the 'word' *sic* should also be in italics as it is Latin.  Same rule applies for "*e.g.*", "*i.e.*", & other Latin 'words'.

Comment: Thank you for that correction. I'll let my error stand since your comment brings it into line.

Comment: @Stan Great... Now, if I'm gonna quote your answer, I'm gonna have to put even another *[sic]* in there.... </comedy>

Comment: @Fiksdal That's pretty sic :)

Comment: Haha, yeah... I get sic when people make language errors.